# Compile error on using generics class hierarchy

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, type-erasure

I have a type inference problem with the use of generics (abstract) class hierarchy in Java 7.

Category class is an *interface*.

```
public interface Category {
    void foo();
}

public abstract class CategoryFilter<E extends Category, T>{

    private E category;

    private Set<T> values = new HashSet<T>();

    public E getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(E category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    public void setValues(Set<T> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public Set<T> getValues() {
        return values;
    }
}
```

SubCategory implements *Category* and have a specific method **bar()**.

```
public class SubCategory implements Category {

    @Override
    public void foo() {

    }

    public void bar(){

    }
}


public abstract class SubCategoryFilter<Q extends SubCategory, T> extends CategoryFilter<Q,T>{

    /*public Q getCategory() {
         return category;
    }*/

    public void buzz(){

    }

}
```

Each *ConcreteClassX* extends *SubCategory*.

```
public final class ConcreteCategoryFilter1 extends SubCategoryFilter<ConcreteClass1, String> {}
public final class ConcreteCategoryFilter2 extends SubCategoryFilter<ConcreteClass2, Integer> {}
```

I don’t want to explain the real business logic here.

Supposing I have a List of SubCategoryFilter l and I want to apply *bar()* on each element of that list **without casting**.

```
List<SubCategoryFilter> l = ...;
SubCategory sub = l.get(0).getCategory(); // here IDE tells me that the return type is Category and not SubCategory
sub.bar();
```

Compilation failure incompatible types
[ERROR] required: com.xxx.yyy.SubCategory
[ERROR] found:    com.xxx.yyy.Category

If I uncomment the previous method everything is fine.

Why does I have to uncomment the previous **valueless** overrided getter *getCategory()* to compile ?

---

Java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: "Supposing I have a List " A list declared how ?

Comment: What is the list type? Can you share with us its declaration?

Comment: edited : List of SubCategoryFilter (List<SubCategoryFilter>)

Comment: It helps if code snippet is copy, paste, and compile. [MCVE] so one does not have to spend 10 minutes putting together a code sample that takes 1 minute to solve

Comment: @efekctive done

Comment: Thanks. But it is a moot point now :-} Maybe you should accept the answer given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<SubCategoryFilter> list` is a raw type as `SubCategoryFilter` is a generic class and you don't specify any generic for it in the variable declaration.

Declare a generic type :

```
List<SubCategoryFilter<SubCategory, ?>> filters = ....
```

And `getCategory()` could so return a `SubCategory` type :

```
SubCategory sub = filters.get(0).getCategory();
```

Comment: OK it solves my compilation problem.

So it means that the bound 'Q extends SubCategory' is only used for checking the type constraint in variable declaration or instantiation. It doesn't affect the return type E of the parent method if Q is not defined. It's not implicit that E is SubCategory if method is called from a raw SubCategoryFilter even if it have a Q extends SubCategory constraint.

Comment: I just read your blog article and got my explanation : http://myjavaadventures.com/blog/2017/07/08/java-generics/

"12) Using raw types has also consequences in terms of inheritancy.
The superclasses (respectively, superinterfaces) of a raw type are the erasures of the superclasses (superinterfaces) of any of the parameterizations of the generic type." Thank you.

Comment: @fdelsert You are welcome. Indeed, raw types have deeper consequences   that we may expect to. So, finally, your raw type takes indeed the erasure of which one of `CategoryFilter` where `E` is a `Category`.